# - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Can i use below method somewhere other than AppDelegate ?if yes how?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a method of the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, and can only be implemented by classes that conform to it.

You can set up a notification to other objects in your app from your app delegate by using the `NSNotificationCenter` object:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didEnterBackground" object:self];
}
```

There is also the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification that you can listen for instead of doing the above.

Register the objects that you want to listen for the notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:someObject selector:@selector(someMethod:) name:@"UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification" object:nil];
```

Comment: Can you give an example on where to put this code, and how to call on it? Another words, is this for saving a whole view, or objects in the view?

Comment: Do NOT use the 1st option. And use the proper constant in the 2nd option instead of hardcoding the notification name.

Answer (score 13):

No, But you can have other objects register for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification. These objects will then be notified at the same time `applicationDidEnterBackground:` is called.

Comment: This answer seems preferable as you aren't posting a redundant notification.